# Send a mail with pdf attachment with help of Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, email-attachments

I want to send an email with a pdf attachment. In another file, I did already realize that task. But in the current case it sends the mail but without an attachment. I compare the current code to the working code but I didn't find a mistake.

```
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var mailAttach = {filename: (subject + "_" + today + ".pdf"), content:pdf, mimeType: 'application/pdf'};

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {
    attachements:[mailAttach],
    cc: recipientCC
  });
```

Comment: Check the `attachments` parameter - there is a typo, an extra `e`

Comment: Oh man... I don´t believe it!
Thank you!

Comment: Hey @OlegValter, can you post it as an answer please?

Comment: Alexander, I know, such typos can be very frustrating :) Cooper already posted as an answer, so you can simply accept it, no worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var mailAttach = {filename: (subject + "_" + today + ".pdf"), content:pdf, mimeType: 'application/pdf'};

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {attachments:[mailAttach],cc: recipientCC});
```